# Migrate instance from EC2 to Google Cloud

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

I have a running Linux instance in Amazon EC2. I'd like to migrate this instance to a Google Cloud VM Instance. I'd like to have the minimum work on this operation, a kind of copy and paste solution. How can I do this?

Comment: Unless you uploaded the original image, there is no way to export an image from one provider to another.

Comment: What is the base image is for your AMI, and how much customization did you make to the AMI?

Comment: I think this link might help:
[Import AMI to GCloud](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/creating-custom-image#import_an_ami_image) I will be implementing this today for one of my requirements (CentOS based AMI). Hope it works well.

Answer (score 10):

You can import an Amazon Machine Image (AMI) to Google Compute Engine but it's not just one operation. There is a section in the [Google Compute Engine documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images#import_an_ami_image) that shows the steps you need to follow in order to achieve your goal.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

With GCP you can use the import feature which forwards to Cloud Endure site, where you can migrate your existing server, virtual on Cloud or non Cloud or even physical machine, to GCP.

You can also import Amazon Linux AMI EC2 instances on AWS.

Cloud Endure provides also live migration, so it does continues replication, if you don't power on your migrated VM on GCP.

It can also be used for just one time migration.

Amazon Linux AMI can be updated on GCP Cloud as well, so no problems with that.

Migration takes few hours depending on size of the source machine. You might need to change the hard drive paths on /etc/fstab to reflect their names on GCP (dev/xvdf --> /dev/sdb, for example).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest one step solution would be using a third party tool to do it for you. There are way many cloud migration vendors that would make this process nearly zero effort. I did that with cloud endure and it went ok, but obviously it involves costs so make sure to check them out.

Answer (score 0):

Found the end to end video which will give an idea how to do migration from ec2 to google cloud.

> link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UT1gPToi7Sg